# What does this orange dot represent in an ROC plot?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, roc

What does this  orange dot represent in an ROC plot?
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] the question to contain the code which produced this graph. All we can say now is that you added the dot yourself.

Answer (score 1):

That comment represents a threshold which provides a False Positive Rate of 0.04, or a specificity of 0.96 and a sensitivity of 0.00, ie. 96% of class 0 is correctly identified but 0% of class 1 is. Therefore it seems to be a higher threshold.

There is no clear reason as to why this point is significant, maybe it's the threshold at which this system operates but it's unclear at this moment as to why this point is highlighted.